Question on LCM and divisibility

Let $d_n= \text{lcm} \{1,2,3..., n \}$ then for which natural numbers $n$ is $$\frac{24 d_n^5}{(n+1)^5} \text{not an integer?}$$

We know that $$ \text{lcm}\{1,2,3,...,n\}.\text{gcd}\{1,2,3,...,n\}=n!$$ So we have $$d_n=\frac{n!}{\text{gcd}\{1,2,3,...,n\}}$$ Hence $$\frac{24 d_n^5}{(n+1)^5}=24\left(\frac{n!}{(n+1)\text{gcd}\{1,2,3,...,n\}}\right)^5$$
Please help me with this problem. Thank you!

If you take $n=5$ you have $d_5=60$ that is divisible for $n+1=6$ and so their fifth powers are divisible as well $\quad$ In general I think that the quantity you describe is not an integer iif $n=p-1$ for some prime

$\text{lcm}{1,2,3,...,n}.\text{gcd}{1,2,3,...,n}=n!$ is incorrect. In fact, $\text{gcd}{1,2,3,\ldots,n}=1$ and $\text{lcm}{1,2,3,...,n}\neq n!$ for many $n$'s.

@SungjinKim Thanks. For which $n$ is my number not an integer?

The question is unclear. Do you mean "for all integers $n$, the quantity is not an integer" (which is false, as whenever $n+1$ is not a prime power, it divides $d_n$) or "it is not true that for all integers $n$ the quantity is an integer" (which is true)?

@MassimilianoFoschi My question is that for which type of integers $n$, the quantity is not an integer.

@Max Then you would have to rewrite your question.

By brute-force calculation, n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31, 36, 40, 42, 46, 48, 52, 58, 60, 63, 66, 70, 72, 78, 80, 82, 88, 96, 100, ...

...which corresponds to https://oeis.org/A181062

As mentioned by Massimiliano, if $n+1$ is not a prime power, then $24d_n^5/(n+1)^5$ is an integer. Let $n+1=dk$ where $1<d\leq n, 1<k\leq n$ and $(d,k)=1$. We have $d|d_n$ and $k|d_n$. This gives $dk|d_n$. Then $24d_n^5/(n+1)^5=24d^5k^5 m / d^5k^5$ for some positive integer $m$. Hence, $24d_n^5/(n+1)^5=24m$ is an integer.
On the other hand, if $n+1=p^k$ is a prime power, then $p^{k-1} || d_n$. This gives $p^{5(k-1)}||d_n^5$ and $p^{5k}||(n+1)^5$. For this prime $p$, the denominator has $p^5$ after making $d_n^5/(n+1)^5$ in the lowest terms. However, $24$ does not have $5$-th powers in the factorization. Hence, we conclude that
$24d_n^5/(n+1)^5$ is not an integer if and only if $n+1$ is a prime power.

$,q\in\Bbb Q,\ 24q^5\in\Bbb Z!\iff! q\in\Bbb Z,$ (else $1<d^5\mid 24,$  for $,d=$ reduced denom of $q),$. So it reduces to when $,n!+!1\nmid {\rm lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n),,$ easily seen to be true $!\iff! n!+!1$ is a prime power. Both of these inferences are duplicates. $\ \ $

($+1$) Please prove that if $n+1$ is not a prime power, then $24d_n^5/(n+1)^5$ is an integer.

@Max It is proved in the first paragraph.
